# Bluemix Secure Gateway - some machines normal and others grayed options

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

As a simple example, has anybody ever typed an ACL-Allow and tried to hit the "+" button but nothing happens. Then you probably have the same problem as me.

I've been working with the Secure Gateways Client for a while. I've worked with it on Windows, Linux, and DataPower. Lately I've noticed a couple of machines where all the configuration options are grayed out, the logs don't show in the GUI, and the test connection fails from the Bluemix cloud. And yet the configuration seems to be the same as the machines where everything is working fine. In the latest case I have 1 Developer's Mac and 1 Windows-2012-R2-on-SoftLayer where this is happening. It's frustrating because it seems to occur at inconvenient times such as when you really need a system to work, such as a QA or STG build where the DEV server was fine but the new ones are not.

Anybody ever experience the "grayed out" phenomenon?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
The latest version of the SG Client (v1.8.0fp4) should resolve these issues.

**Original Answer**

This is a known issue with the Secure Gateway Client GUI that causes it to not reflect an accurate status of the installed SG Client.  The GUI is largely a standalone piece of the client, so the underlying functionality of the SG Client isn't affected by this issue; however, it leads to situations such as the `+` to add an ACL rule from the GUI not actually communicating the rule to the SG Client and thereby not applying the rule.  All functionality generally available from the Client GUI is available via the Client CLI as another option for configuring your client.

If you can provide some output from the log files being written by each installation, those would be helpful for identifying potential issues across each environment.